# Generic URL config for all environment .NET

Tags: c#, redirect, payment

I'm having an issue with generic redirect url for my payment method

```
public async Task<IActionResult> PaymentCallback()
{
    string url = protocol 
    logger.LogInformation("Start save bill");
    var response = await paymentService.PaymentExecute(Request.Query);

    return Redirect("http://localhost:5173/success");
}
```

and in appsetting.json

```
"PaymentCallBack": {
"ReturnUrl": "https://localhost:7089/api/Payment/callback-payment"}
```

The problem is that localhost URL won't work if I start deploy product, so are there any documents or guides about creating a general URL that works on all environment?

Comment: Is `https://localhost:7089` the application that has the code `PaymentCallback`?

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama yes, and http://localhost:5173 is belong to frontend code